# Save setting in Windows Registry to prompt for a restart when opening a Windows application

Tags: c#, registry

I want to store a value in the Windows Registry through my application so that I can prompt a restart when my application is reopened.

This restart prompt should be user specific.

What is the appropriate location to add this setting in the Registry?

Comment: What where the options you explored?

Comment: You seem to have decided to use the registry. What issues are you facing when using the registry to save your data?

Comment: I'm unsure on which location in the Registry I should store the setting in.

Comment: @naren.katneni Right that is useful info - so update your question with that. Also your reply to David Hope's answer is useful info too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Microsoft Article on setting the registry using c#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e7chcf.aspx

The questions that you need to consider are:

1. Where in the registry are you planning on putting the value? HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, HKEY_CURRENT_USER. If you put it in HKEY_CURRENT_USER, then if another user logs on, you won't get the prompt
2. What permissions does your user have for writing to the registry? In some businesses, most users are non-admin and likely cannot write anything to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

There may be better ways to accomplish what you are trying to do (change in setting in your app settings for instance). But that depends on what you are doing and why.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm inclined towards using HKEY_CURRENT_USER, as the restart prompt is user specific.